# Automate power BI processes

Tags: powerbi

I'm working on a Power BI project that:
1/Takes data from Google Sheets 
2/Makes some modifications with power Query (or any other program) 
3/Create the rapport 
4/send it to the client 
what i want to do is to automate these 4 steps.
the data's structure is the same, the content and the title of the columns are different from google sheets to other (depend on the client).
I'm new with BI and pretty inexperienced with Power BI so apologies if there is a simple answer to this question or if i didn't explain it as well as possible.
I need your help please.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately power bi has no built in connections for google sheets.

give this article a try [How to connect google sheet with power bi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45945815/how-to-connect-google-sheet-with-power-bi)

If that doesn't work you can try getting connector or API etc... you Can also explore using VBA (selenium) or some form of web automation to get it done.

some other workaround you can try is using smart sheet or Microsoft Excel